# Create cycles in MS Dynamics CRM Workflow

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm-2011, workflow-foundation

I'm trying to find a way to create cycle in MS Dynamics CRM using Workflow functionality.

But so far it seems to be impossible out of the box. Is it possible to implement cycle functionality using custom workflow activity?

If yes, so then how?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "cycles" some more? Not sure what you mean..

Comment: @SunilAlbuquerque I want to iterate through items liked to the record. For example: I'm running workflow on opportunity record, but I also want to execute some code on products linked to this opportunity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to iterate inside a workflow the related records (for example all the contacts that belong to an account) you need a Custom Workflow Activity, and it already exists:

[CRM 2011 Distribute Workflow Activity](http://crm2011distributewf.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You are right, it's not possible out of the box.
You need to write a Custom Workflow Activity to do this.

This blog post has information on how you can write a custom workfolow activity:
http://dynamic-crm.com/custom-workflow-activity/